# Comparitive operator not working in Julia script file when used in control flow with conditional operator

Tags: julia

I have tried different operators <,>,etc. Nothing seems to work when I combine comparative operators with conditional operators.

```
e = readline()

if e == 0
    println("e is equal to 0")
else
        println("e is not equal to 0")
end
```

The expected result is obvious, if e = 0, prints e is equal to 0, if e != 0, prints e is not equal to 0.

However, it always prints the bottom line, e is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `readline` returns a string, which is never equal to an integer (by the definition of `==` Julia uses).

Here are some possible ways to achieve what you want:

- Compare to a string literal instead: `if e == "0"`
- Use `tryparse`: `if tryparse(Int, e) == 0` (will return `nothing` if `e` is not a number literal)
- Use `parse`, but with `try`/`catch` instead of an `if`:

  ```
  try
      p = parse(Int, e)
      p == 0 ? println("e is 0") : println("e is not 0")
  catch
      println("not even an integer.")
  end
  ```

Comment: In C++ I can write ```int c; std::cin >> c; if(c == 0){//dothis}``` Is there a way in Julia to read in a non-string?

Comment: I figured out how to read in an integer. ```e = parse(Int64, readline()) ``` does the trick. You can test this using ```println(typeof(e)) ```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the `if` returns the branch that you don't expect is those given to you by @phg (you got a `String` by `readline()`).

For my code I use the following function to parse user-provided data given in a terminal:

```
function getUserInput(T=String,msg="")
  print("$msg ")
  if T == String
      return readline()
  else
    try
      return parse(T,readline())
    catch
     println("Sorry, I could not interpret your answer. Please try again")
     getUserInput(T,msg)
    end
  end
end

sentence = getUserInput(String,"Which sentence do you want to be repeated?");
n        = getUserInput(Int64,"How many times do you want it to be repeated?");
[println(sentence) for i in 1:n]
println("Done!")
```